# Class name is a reserved word when query provider compiles ELINQ query to ESQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1, reserved-words, entity-sql

I'm receiving this error:

> System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing
>   the database. See the InnerException for details. --->
>   System.Data.EntitySqlException: 'All' is a reserved keyword and cannot
>   be used as an alias, unless it is escaped. Near line 1, column 1. at
>   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlLexer.MapUnescapedIdentifier(String
>   symbol) at
>   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlLexer.MapIdentifierOrKeyword(String
>   symbol) at System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlLexer.yylex() at
>   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlParser.yylex() at
>   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlParser.yyparse() at
>   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlParser.Parse(String query) at
>   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlQuery.Parse(String commandText,
>   ParserOptions parserOptions) at
>   System.Data.Common.EntitySql.CqlQuery.CompileCommon(String
>   commandText, Perspective perspective, ParserOptions parserOptions,
>   Func`3 compilationFunction) at
>   System.Data.Objects.EntitySqlQueryState.Parse() at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateInlineQueryOfT(ObjectQuery
>   inlineQuery) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, ConstantExpression linq) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)
>
> ...< snip >...
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1
>   predicate) at MyNamespace.All.GetEmptyList() in All.cs:
>   line 35

which seems to be caused by the name of the test class being 'All'.

```
[TestClass]
public class All : Service
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetEmptyList()
    {
        var actualList = MyItems.Where(item => item.Id < 0);
    }
}
```

The `MyItems` property is a public property on the `Service` base class:

```
public IQueryable<MyItem> MyItems
{
    get { return Set<MyItem>(); }
}
```

I presume that my class name is being converted into an ESQL type, which turns it into a reserved word. However, I have no (direct) control over that, and as the ESQL and TSQL is not my concern, I don't think this problem should bubble-up, especially as I don't see what I can do about it, apart from rename my class (if I change it to 'All2', everything works fine.)

Why doesn't the expression parser (whereever specifically, maybe `ExpressionConverter.Convert()` or `TranslateInlineQueryOfT`) automatically escape reserved words?

Is there a way way I can fix this problem?  Changing the class name is a hack.

(Running code-first with .NET 4, EF 4.1, against MS SQL 2008 R2.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually changing the class name would be a huge aid to comprehensibility.

All what?

The entity framework is generic, where would it get a list of reserved words from and how.
If there is a fix I suspect it will be an attribute to either escape or map the class name for use in the back end. It's the way I'd do it anyway.

Comment: Within the wider context 'All' is clear, I've just left that out.  I take your point, however, given that there is a provider (here  the System.Data.SqlClient), this could implement the functionality. Furthermore, escaping by default would avoid such problems surely? It's one of annoying aspects of ORMs where they aren't storage-agnostic.    Changing the db-backing to an in-memory collection doesn't raise the problem- which suggests the 'UNION' statement in ESQL itself isn't the problem, but the TSQL one.

Comment: Nah it's not TSQL, if you were going native it would have been [ALL], something in the ORM should be wrapping everything up in whatever the DBMS uses to wrap 'object' names

Comment: Changing the backing store to memory won't help here, I realised.  If it's not the TSQL, then, it seems to me that it should be dealt with automatically (and probably even if it is TSQL).